# Вдова положила всё(,) что имела

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Нужна ли здесь запятая и как изменится пунктуация, если убрать слово *всё*?

- Вдова положила, что имела. Придаточное изъяснительное? Или: Вдова положила что имела. Что имела — дополнение.
- Может, можно и в этом предложении: Вдова положила всё что имела, *что имела* считать дополнением, а *всё* определением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вдова положила всё, что имела, все пропитание свое** (из Евангелия).

Не имеет смысла переделывать предложение, так как определение синтаксической функции (устойчивый оборот или придаточное предложение) зависит от контекста, от значения или даже от объема опорного слова (глагола).

Всегда нужно анализировать реальные предложения, любые изменения нежелательны.

**Примеры с устойчивым выражением** (значение дополнения): **отдала что имела** (= всё); отдала что могла.  Я за Бога отдал что имел: пять монет...